# Angular 2 (click) sometimes does not fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

In my Angular 2 / Bootstrap / AdminLTE I have the following template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-cutlery" (click)='munch(1);'></i></button>
```

Which is calling this method:

```
async munch(amount: number) {
    console.log("Start")
    await this.food.redeem(amount);
    console.log("Stop")
}
```

The button is embedded in a navigation bar. Then I press it, there seems to be about a 2/3 random chance that it fires. However, in about 1/3 of all cases nothing happens, I don't even see `Start` on the console.

Is there anything that might interfere with how Angular 2 fires these click events? My page is relatively vanilla, and I am pretty sure I am not messing with any low-level DOM / event handling / JavaScript myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be, that your i-tag is smaller than your button?
Why not put the (click) inside the button instead of the i tag?